# Setting up an array of floats and printing them in MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, floating-point, mips

I am having trouble setting up an Array of floating point integers and then printing them... 
I need to do some arithmetic, I can figure that out, but then to print it to the screen.

```
.data
    time:       .float 310, 393, 422, 494, 514 
miles:      .float 0.0, 42.2, 78.8, 129.4, 133.0
.text  

la $a1, time         # put address of list into $a1
l.s $f1 ($a1)

l.s $f1, ($t3)       # get the value from the array cell

li $v0, 2           
l.s $a0, $f1            
syscall
```

Im not sure what I need to be doing to get to print a certain value of the array. This confuses me on how to call a certain float number and also how to print it. I have been looking around on the internet for a couple hours and it is getting frustrating. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with the code? You load a float from the address in `$a1`, you print it with syscall 2, you increase `$a1` by 4 and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print a floating point number you have to use `syscall` 2 using `$f12` as the input float to print.
E.g:

```
.data
    time:       .float 310, 393, 422, 494, 514 
    miles:      .float 0.0, 42.2, 78.8, 129.4, 133.0
.text  

    la $a1, time         # put address of list into $a1
    l.s $f12 ($a1)       
    li $v0, 2           
    syscall              # This will print 310.0

    l.s $f12 4($a1)
    syscall              # And this will print 393.0
```

Comment: So if I were to mulitiply some floats, how would i return their value?

Comment: I can mul.s f1 and f2 into f3. how do i print f3?

Comment: @DDukesterman: just copy the contents of `f3` onto `f12` before issuing the syscall. That is, `mov.s $f12, $f3`

Answer (score 0):

```
li $t0, 13      #terminating value
li $t1, 4       #byte shifting 
li $t2, 1       #i increments by 1  
la $a1, time            # put address of time into $a1
la $a2, miles       # put address of miles into $a2 

add $a1, $a1, $t1
add $a2, $a2, $t1
l.s $f1, ($a1)
l.s $f2, ($a2)
mul.s $f3, $f1, $f2
s.s $f3, ($a3)

li $v0, 2           
l.s $f12, ($a3)         
syscall
```

when ever I multiply how f1 and f2 and put them into f3, how do I print f3?

Answer (score 0):

We always use even floating regester except `$f0` and `$f12` , because it's for reading and writing values respectivly ..